# Babel 'protoToAssign' transformer and ES6 class inheritance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Here is [simple plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EQO4RjYRmKSf62dahESN?p=preview) involving class inheritance, with shims and Babel options being set to `stage: 0, loose: 'all'`:

```
class Hello {
  static address = ', world!';
  greeting = 'Hello';

  constructor() {
    this.greet();
  }

  greet() {
    document.write(this.greeting + Hello.address);
  }
}

class Hi extends Hello {
  greeting = 'Hi';

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

new Hi().greet();
```

Apparently, it works as it should in IE5.5+.

What are the circumstances where Babel [`spec.protoToAssign`](http://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/spec/proto-to-assign/) transformer can be beneficial (or undesirable) for ES6/ES7 transpiled OOP code that is targeted to legacy browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 class inheritance also means that

```
Hi.address
```

would work because `Hi` inherits from `Hello`. Without `protoToAssign`, this will not work in IE<=10.

The general case is exactly as described on that page however. IE<=10 does not support assignment of `__proto__` so if you rely on behavior that relied on it, it will not work.

This is all covered in the [caveats](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/) page for Babel.

Comment: Great, thanks, I see. Is static property the only thing in Babel class implementation that relies on `__proto__`? I've recently stumbled upon [this article](http://ricostacruz.com/til/babel-ie-class-inheritance.html) that asserts that 'super' relies on 'Object.getPrototypeOf' and thus will fail in old IEs, but it wasn't so in my experience, also haven't met 'Object.getPrototypeOf' in transpiled code.

Comment: This is all covered in the [caveats](http://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/caveats/) page for Babel, see the section about classes. You probably want to enable "loose mode" if you need to support IE<= 8.

Comment: Sure, thank you, I already enabled loose it in the example above.